# open a field after allowedits in access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a huge form in access which needs to prevent users from editing the details in it.. I have done that by setting Me.Allowedits to false. But there is one field which I need to keep as open  to editing. To do this I have jus placed the code to open the field after the allowedits part in two places where the allowedit code occurs. the flow on debugging was like this

```
   Load 
Me.allowedits =false
if condition=true
field.locked=false
field.enalble=true
```

The same thing I have replicated in current event of the form.Basically I have just kept the code wherever the allowedits was set to fasle.
But my field is still locked and cannot edit it.Is this because once we set allowedits=false the fields in the page cannot be made editable again.
Is there any other alternative?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Is this one field bound or unbound?

Comment: Thanks for the response andre .....the field I am talking about is jus a simple text box where the user selects a date and and stores it in the table...so yes its bound i guess

Comment: You can set the controls to prevent editing (Locked = True), rather than the form. It is often quicker if you add a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you can't use a form-level setting.

If this is constant (the fields are **always** locked), simply set all other controls to `Locked = True`.

If it's dynamic, use a procedure like this:

```
Private Sub SetEditable(EnableEdit As Boolean)

    Dim ctl As Control

    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        ' The main editable control types (add more if they occur on your form)
        If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Or ctl.ControlType = acComboBox Or _ 
           ctl.ControlType = acCheckBox Or ctl.ControlType = acSubform Then

            If ctl.Name = "MySpecialDateField" Then
                    ' Always editable
                    ctl.Locked = False
                Else
                    ctl.Locked = Not EnableEdit
                    ' If you want to provide a visual feedback: 
                    ' 0 = Flat (locked), 2 = Sunken (editable)
                    ctl.SpecialEffect = IIf(EnableEdit, 2, 0)
                End If
            End If

        End If
    Next ctl

End Sub
```

Comment: They are controls, not fields. : )

Comment: Thank for your suggestions Andre...I have noted it down incase I need it some other ime...Currently I have locked each and every field individually...did involve a lot of manual work but I needed it quick